# "First Steps" shortcut is missing after successful DB2 installation

Tags: java, windows, db2

I have installed a DB2 Express-c verion 10.1 on Windows-XP, after successful installation, It has not asked to create a SAMPLE database as I saw in 9.7 version.

Then I go to launch it maunally as `'Start > Programs > IBM DB2 > DB2COPY1 (Default) > First Steps'`. But I have not found any shortcut for this. Then I opened the **db2cmd** and run the command **db2fs** to launch it maunally but got the error:

```
'db2fs' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Whats wrong with my DB2 setup??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you downloaded the "light" packaged version of DB2 Express-C.  It only has English localization, and does not include Text Search, Configuration Assistant, or First Steps.  For these savings, the download is 293 Mb.

The "full"  DB2 express-c is about 425 Mb.

FYI, you can create the sample database by executing the `db2sampl` command from a DB2 Command Window.